# rsync: how to replicate full directory structure

Tags: rsync

I would like to use rsync to sync some directories from a remote server to my local machine. In order to keep the files organized i would like rsync to create/copy the whole path with all the parent directories.

I am using ssh with certificate files so no manual login is required.

If i use it like following it copies the file.crt but does not create the parent directories:

```
rsync -ave ssh user1@10.10.10.10:/opt/dir/data/file.crt /home/user1/
```

If i try to use the -R --recursive option it fails with the error below:

```
 rsync -ave --recurisive ssh user1@10.10.10.10:/opt/dir/data/file.crt /home/user1/
```

or with -R

```
 rsync -aveR ssh user1@10.10.10.10:/opt/dir/data/file.crt /home/user1/
```

> Unexpected remote arg: user1@10.10.10.10:/opt/dir/data/file.crt
>
> rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1361) [sender=3.1.2]

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here: first, the `-R` and `--recurisive` options are *not* the same (and "recurisive" is misspelled). `-R` is the short form of `--relative`, which is what you want (it includes the full path of the source). There is a `--recursive` option (short form: `-r`), but that's implied by `-a`, and also irrelevant here because you're copying a single file, not a directory.

Second, when you add the new option, you're putting it between `-ave` and `ssh`, but `ssh` is there as a parameter to the `-e` option, so it must follow immediately after `-e`. The way you're writing it, `rsync` is interpreting `-R` or whatever as a parameter to `-e`, and `ssh` as a completely separate argument, and therefore getting completely confused.

But you shouldn't need `-e ssh` anyway -- that's almost always the default, so you should be able to just leave it off. Therefore, try this:

```
rsync -avR user1@10.10.10.10:/opt/dir/data/file.crt /home/user1/
```

If that doesn't work, try this instead:

```
rsync -avR -e ssh user1@10.10.10.10:/opt/dir/data/file.crt /home/user1/
```